# Parsing Database Record in SingalR Javascript Client

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am learning about the ASP.NET Core SignalR. I wrote a basic program under MVC framework that interacts with a SQLite database. This program allows user to perform CRUD operations on the database. I introduced SignalR hub in the program. The server periodically gets list of records from the database, and pushes to the client using hub SendAsync function. In a Javascript hub client,  I am trying to parse (and display) the received messages. Everything works (getting list of items from the database, sending through hub) except when  accessing an element of an item I get **undefined** message, although there are three items retrieved from the database with valid values assigned to each element.

**Schema** for the database (under '**Models**' folder):

```
public class IenState
{
    public int Id { get; set; }   

    public ulong NetId { get; set; }
    public ushort NodeId { get; set; } 
}
```

Sending messages from **sever-end** of the hub:

```
var ienStates = from m in dbcontext.IenState select m;                           
var listdb = await ienStates.ToListAsync();  //here 3-items recovered
await hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("IenStateDb", listdb);
```

Javascript **hub client** (named **IenStateHub.js**):

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("/ienStateHub")
.configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
.build();

connection.start().then(function () {        
    document.getElementById("p_nets").innerHTML = "IenStateHub is   'CONNECTED'";               
});

connection.on("IenStateDb", function(message){      
  var dbitem; 
  for (dbitem in message) 
  {            
    document.getElementById("p_nets").innerHTML  = "NetId:" + dbitem.NetId;                
  }       
});
```

Where '**p_nets**' is an HTML element in '**Index.cshtml**'. The hub client (IenStateHub.js) is appended at the end of Index.cshtml as follows:

```
<script src="~/lib/signalr/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/IenStateHub.js"></script>
```

Any help to resolve this parsing issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: First of all it seems like you're incorrectly using `for in` loop(it should be used for iterating through object properties, so in each iteration you would get the first element). Try to use just `for` loop of `forEach` method. Also I would suggest to check out the actual received message(e.g. `console.log(message);`): maybe your property names are converted to camel case so you actually have `netId`, not `NetId`.

Comment: @Roman Koliada,  Displaying received message in the HTML element, `document.getElementById("p_nets").innerHTML =  message;` gives  **[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]**.  With  `foreach(dbitem in message)`, program never enters the loop body.

Comment: You're iterating incorrectly. See this article: https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-for-loop-foreach/ . Also how are you going to put 3 values into a single `p_nets` html element? At the moment only last element will be displayed.

Comment: @Roman Koliada, Thanks I will read the article. I am beginner to all these tools, and trying to learn things.  In the p_nets, I am just trying to verify if I get something valid - will be able to see the last value in the list - just to keep it simple. But eventually, I will display all items in an HTML table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following method works:

```
$.each(message, function(index, obj) {
    console.log( index + ": " + obj );
    $.each(obj, function( key, value ) {
        console.log( key + ": " + value );
      });
 });
```

This is based on one of the approaches described in the [link](https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-for-loop-foreach/) (mentioned by **@Roman Koliada**).

Now I am not sure whether this is the most efficient way to access different elements in each item/object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to check your message on the client side:

```
connection.on("IenStateDb", function(message) {  
  message.forEach(function(dbitem, index, array) {
     console.log(dbitem);//should output your db item into the browser console.
     //document.getElementById("p_nets").innerHTML  = "NetId:" + dbitem.NetId;  
  });
});
```

Comment: With this method (in the browser console) I am getting **<unavailable>**. I am wondering, do I need to reshape data on the sending side  into some specific format, or it is just a problem of parsing on the receive side.